# SSH remote command executing a script

Tags: bash, ssh

I have two hosts, hosts A and B. A has a script (generate) that compiles my thesis:

```
#!/bin/sh
pdflatex Thesis.tex
```

When running this command on host A (console window) it works perfectly.

I am basically trying to connect from host B to A and run the generation command as an ssh remote command. All the keys are properly set. When I run the command, I get the following:

```
hostB> ssh user@hostA exec ~/Thesis/generate
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `Thesis.tex'.
<*> Thesis.tex
```

I tried adjusting the script so that it considers the directory:

```
pdflatex ~/Thesis/Thesis.tex
```

But because the Thesis.tex inputs some others files (images), I get an error message.

I presume the problem is some sort of enviroment that doesn't exist in remote commands. How do I fix this?

Comment: what does `generate` look like?

Comment: The script `generate` is simply `pdflatex Thesis.tex`, as shown in my message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh` will run your command in your home directory. You probably wanted to run it in your `~/Thesis` directory.

Just `cd` first and it should be fine:

```
ssh user@hostA 'cd ~/Thesis && ./generate'
```